# Copy controls of panel to other panel

Tags: c#, winforms, copy, controls, panel

I want to add controls of one panel to other,without removing controls of first panel, I am using this code, but it removes controls from source panel,is there any way to do this? I used this link,

```
public void CopyControls(Panel source,Panel destination)
{
        ctrls.Clear();
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {                    
                foreach (Control c in Source.Controls)
                {
                    ctrls.Add(c);
                }
                desination.Controls.Clear();
                desination.Controls.AddRange(ctrls.ToArray());
            }));
        }
        else
        {
          //  List<Control> ctrls = new List<Control>();
            foreach (Control c in source.Controls)
            {
                ctrls.Add(c);
            }
            desination.Controls.Clear();
            desination.Controls.AddRange(ctrls.ToArray());
        }
}
```

Comment: you have create shallow copy of each control object

Comment: Your code is __moving__ the controls. You have to create __new__ versions of the controls; no easy way other than setting __all__ relevant properties.

Comment: The marked duplicate answers the question you asked; i.e. "you can't". The comment above explains that you need to create new instances of the controls by creating the new instances and copying values from the original to the new. If you have problems figuring that out, please post a new question, including [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you've tried.